UrlLauncher reopen google maps
I am making an app that needs to open Google Maps by passing waypoints. But at some point the route may change, how can I send the new route and monitor it to perform functions based on the current position?
getDirections(List<dynamic> escolaComDistancia) async {
    print(escolaComDistancia);
    List<PolylineWayPoint> polylineWayPoints = [];

    // Utiliza a posição atual como origem
    LatLng origin = LatLng(latitude.value, longitude.value);

    // Define a localização da última criança como destino
    Crianca ultimaCrianca = escolaComDistancia.last;
    LatLng destination = LatLng(ultimaCrianca.escola.latitude, ultimaCrianca.escola.longitude);

    for (int i = 0; i < escolaComDistancia.length - 1; i++) {
      Crianca crianca = escolaComDistancia[i];
      polylineWayPoints.add(
        PolylineWayPoint(location: "${crianca.escola.latitude},${crianca.escola.longitude}"),
      );
    } // Adiciona os waypoints como string
    String waypoints = polylineWayPoints.map((wp) => wp.location).join('|');

    String googleMapsUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1"
        "&origin=${origin.latitude},${origin.longitude}"
        "&destination=${destination.latitude},${destination.longitude}";

    if (waypoints.isNotEmpty) {
      googleMapsUrl += "&waypoints=$waypoints";
    }

    if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(googleMapsUrl))) {
      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(googleMapsUrl));
      print('abriu');
    } else {
      throw 'Não foi possível abrir o Google Maps.';
    }

it generates the new link and reaches the urllauncher however if maps is open it does not update the route, I wanted to update the link in the Google Maps app.

Are you able to provide a sample proof of concept?
